# lzwの圧縮、解凍について

Tags: c#, アルゴリズム

お世話になります。

今回、初めてGIFファイルの勉強をしようと、lzwの圧縮、解凍をC#で組んでみたのですが、
どうもうまくいきません。

圧縮まではうまくいっているようなのですが、解凍しようとすると、余計なところに『0』が
入ってしまい、正しく解凍されません。

ほかサイト様など、さまざまなところを拝見させていただいているのですが、どうも
原因がわかりません。

原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

尚、まだ勉強中のため、バイト単位でなく、0から255までのテキストデータの
パターンで練習していますのでご了承ください。

下記にソースコードを記述します。

```
    private Dictionary<string, int> hsDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private Dictionary<string,string > hsDec = new Dictionary< string,string>();
    private List<int> arch = new List<int>();

    private string[] stBuff = null;

    // 圧縮
    public int[] enc(string[] values)
    {
        for (int d0 = 0; d0 < 8; d0++)
        {
            this.hsDic.Add("" + d0, d0);
            this.hsDec.Add("" + d0,"" +  d0);
        }
        bool eof = false;

        this.stBuff = values;

        string w = "";
        string k = "";

        int skip = 0;

        int idx = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            //  idxで指定した文字を取得
            w = stBuff[idx];

            //  skipはidxの一文字後から開始
            skip = 0;
            if (this.hsDic.Count == 20)
            {
                int a = 0;
            }

            while (true)
            {
                skip++;

                if(idx + skip >= stBuff.Length)
                {
                    eof = true;
                    break;
                }
                k = stBuff[idx + skip];
                if (this.hsDic.ContainsKey(w + "," + k))
                {
                    w = w + "," + k;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(eof)
            {
                break;
            }
            this.hsDic.Add(w + "," + k, this.hsDic.Count);
            this.arch.Add(this.hsDic[w]);
            idx += skip;
        }
        //  最後の一文字

        this.arch.Add(this.hsDic[w]);
        return this.arch.ToArray();
    }

    // 解凍
    public string[] dec2(int[] pattern)
    {
        for (int d0 = 0; d0 < 8; d0++)
        {
            this.hsDic.Add("" + d0, d0);
            this.hsDec.Add("" + d0,"" +  d0);
        }

        bool eof = false;

        int w = -1;
        int k = -1;

        string ww = "";
        string kk = "";
        int skip = 0;

        int idx = 0;

        List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            //  idxで指定した文字を取得
            w = pattern[idx];
            ww = this.hsDec["" + w];
            //  skipはidxの一文字後から開始
            skip = 1;

            if (this.hsDec.Count == 20)
            {
                int a = 0;
            }

            if (idx + skip >= pattern.Length)
            {
                eof = true;
                break;
            }

            k = pattern[idx + skip];
            kk = this.hsDec["" + k];

            this.hsDec.Add("" + this.hsDec.Count, ww + "," + kk);
            lst.Add(this.hsDec["" + w]);
            idx += skip;
        }
        ////  最後の一文字

        lst.Add(ww);
        return lst.ToArray();
    }
```

テストパターン

```
7,6,3,5,2,3,0,2,0,0,3,6,5,4,0,7,2,1,4,4,1,1,2,4,0,6,3,6,1,4,7,3,5,2,3,5,7,7,5,3,3,4,3,3,2,4,5,0,1,0,0,7,7,2,2,6,4,2,0,3,4,7,2,0,5,5,4,4,0,0,3,1,2,2,1,1,7,0,0,6,5,1,0,7,6,
```

上記のパターンを使用しています。

ここまでですらうまくいっていないため、解凍時に辞書に登録されていないものは、
wとwの最初の一文字を足したものを辞書に追加する…などといったこともまだ行っていません。

まだテスト中のため、コードも汚くて申し訳ありませんが、ぜひご教授いただけますよう、
お願いいたします。

Comment: コードブロックに使うインデント（スペース4つ）は半角スペースでないといけません。追加された部分は全角スペースでインデントされているので、そこだけコードブロックが途絶えています。

Comment: もっと言うと、コードを範囲選択して、エディタの上の `{}` ボタンを押すと簡単に装飾できますので、手で半角スペースを打つのが面倒でしたらお試しください。

Comment: 細かな説明、ありがとうございました。これから活用してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

主要な原因として`dec2`の下記の個所に2点誤りがあります。

> ```
>       k = pattern[idx + skip];
>       kk = this.hsDec["" + k];
>       this.hsDec.Add("" + this.hsDec.Count, ww + "," + kk);
> ```

まず3行目で登録している値ですが、`kk`は先頭の文字のみを使用しなくてはなりません。ですので`kk[0]`のようにしてください。

次に2行目ですが、ここでキー`k`が登録されているとは限りません。

たとえば`0,0,0`というデータを圧縮すると、まずコード`8`に`0,0`が登録されて`0,8`が出力されます。これを復号しようとした場合、`0`の次のコード`8`が登録される前に`8`を参照しようとして例外が発生します。

このためディクショナリに後続のコードが登録されていない場合の処理を行わなくてはなりませんが、圧縮時に直前に追加したコードが使用されているため両コードは平文の先頭が一致していると判断できます。ですのでキーがない場合は`kk`として`ww`を使用します。

あともう一点あげると`ww`はカンマ区切りなので`lst.Add(ww)` (二か所)は`lst.AddRange(ww.Split(','))`が正しいです。ここを直せば少なくとも質問のデータについてはラウンドトリップします。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。おかげさまで、何とか正しく動作しました。以前から習得しようと思っていたもののため、理解できたのでとてもうれしいです。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。